# Sum of residuals squared

Tags: regression, residuals, sums-of-squares

How can I write the sum of squared residuals as a function of the sample mean and variance of $y$, given that the regression equation is:

$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1(x-\bar{x}) + \epsilon$

where $\bar{x}$ is the average of the $x$'s.

I want to calculate the sum of the squared residuals using only the 1st and 2nd sample moments of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: If this is for some course, please include the self-study tag.

Comment: A small hint: what's $\hat \beta_0$?

Comment: well its the average of the y values, but I don't see how that helps...

Comment: @ Glen_b I mean I still have the b1_hat floating around. I guess if I know b1_hat i could plug values in after expanding the expression but it would not be very nice. Sorry I am just not seeing it even though I actually spent about 3 hours today trying some different, and probably very wrong, methods.

Comment: AH! I just got it sorry I was being silly. Thanks for the hint Glen_b :)

Comment: @Mauro, you should post your answer to this question so that the question doesn't seem unresolved.

Comment: @MauroAugusto I don't think you were being silly at all; these things are not always obvious the first time you do them. If you had still got nowhere I'd have given another hint. It's good that you seem to have got somewhere on your own, with so tiny a hint. Are you able to write an answer, as BabakP suggests?

Comment: as the answer by @Y.C. suggests, you need the covariance or correlation of x and y $$\hat\beta_1 = \frac{cov(x,y)}{\hat\sigma_x^2} = \hat\rho_{xy} \frac{\hat\sigma_y}{\hat\sigma_x}$$ Just the first and second moments of each is not sufficient. You can have various relationships (different $\rho_{xy}$) between x and y while the two have the same mean (first moment) and variance (second moment).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my deduction, hope it helps.

Given the regression equation,

\begin{equation}
\hat{y} = \beta_0 + \beta_1(x - \overline{x}) + \epsilon
\end{equation}

By minimizing the sum of squared errors, we can get

\begin{equation}
\hat{\beta_0} =  \overline{y}\\
\hat{\beta_1} =  \frac{Cov(x, y)}{Var(x)}
\end{equation}

Then, assuming there are n samples, we can calculate the sum of squared residuals

\begin{eqnarray*}
RSS&=&\sum_{i}(y_i - \hat{y_i})^2\\
&=&\sum_{i}(y_i - \hat{\beta_0} - \hat{\beta_1}(x_i - \overline{x}))^2\\
&=&\sum_{i}(y_i - \overline{y} - \hat{\beta_1}(x_i - \overline{x}))^2\\
&=&\sum_{i}(y_i - \overline{y})^2 + \hat{\beta_1}^2\sum_{i}(x_i - \overline{x})^2 -2\hat{\beta_1}\sum_{i}(x_i - \overline{x})(y_i - \overline{y})\\
&=&n(Var(y) - \frac{Cov(x,y)^2}{Var(x)})
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: You could write that last line also as:

$$n(1-\rho^2) Var(y)$$

which relates it to $R^2 = 1- SS_{res}/SS_{tot}$ or differently written:

$$SS_{res} = SS_{tot} (1-R^2) = nVar(y) (1-R^2)$$